# Can I damage a grain mill by milling corn or sorghum?

Tags: grain, mill

I recently purchased a Crankandstein 2S grain mill. It is currently being "assembled" and I am considering making some silly beers with grains around the house; like corn and sorghum.

Can corn damage a grain mill? The mill looks really strong, but I would rather make sure beforehand.

How can I test if a grain might damage a mill?

Comment: Ask the manufacturer or supplier you purchased it from. Then if it has problems, you can rely on the warranty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would doubt it - the mill is made of steel, which I imagine is orders of magnitude more robust than any cereal you put through it. But if in doubt contact the manufacturer to be sure.

Comment: The manufacturer replied that the mill will not be damaged, but that high water content may cause the rollers to get gummed up.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt with my father-in-law's corn proved that the mill was incapable of damaging the corn.   I think it was probably due to the gap being too narrow.

You may need to adjust your mill to crush the corn.   Also realize that a mill meant for brewing isn't going to make cornmeal or flour, but crushed/cracked grain.